# Dependency not injected although service exists

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, coffeescript, yeoman

So I've been working on an Angular.js project for awhile now that will be used in a competition, and halfway through I realized I needed a plugin system to dynamically load some necessary code at runtime. Thus far i've found that angular.js isn't very accommodating to loading services at runtime. Due to the code only being available to competitors at competition time I can only provide an example of what isn't working.

```
// ex1.coffee

mainModule = angular.module('mainModule')

mainModule.service('needed', () ->
    @neededFunc() ->
        console.log "just an example"
    return this    

mainModule.service('ex1', ($injector) ->
    @loadFile = (u, pluginName) ->
        $.ajax
            dataType: "script",
            url: u,
            data: null,
            success: (jqxhr, textStatus) =>
                $injector.invoke([pluginName, (plugin) =>
                    plugin.testFunc()
            error: (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
                console.log "couldn't find the script"
    return this


// ex2.coffee

mainModule = angular.module('mainModule')

mainModule.service('ex2', (needed) ->
    @testFunc = () ->
        needed.neededFunc()
        console.log "in this dynamically loaded file"
    return this
```

Implicit things: There is an existing module called mainModule. Jquery and angular have been previously included in the dom. ex1.js is already included in the dom while ex2.js has not yet been included in the dom. u is a url to the file ex2.js and pluginName = "ex2" . When the success handler is called, the invoke function fails, saying that an ex2Provider does not exist. However, if I breakpoint in the success callback and check the mainModule._invokeQueue, there does exist an array with the service name "ex2" so it definitely has an existing recipe within the module, but the $injector.invoke call still fails. If I modify the success handler to call, $injector.has pluginName, it fails. Can someone tell me how the module can have knowledge of a provider for this dynamically loaded service but not be able to inject it into a function call with $injector? 
The project is a yeoman project built with grunt.

Still learning angular so if there is some concept I'm missing or stating wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Are you sure it's ex2Provider that is missing? Often AngularJS gives dependencies errors as a chain, and people misread the error by assuming the first reference in the chain is what triggered the error.

Comment: Based upon the example. ex2 would fail is the dependency `needed` didn't exist. That would cause ex2Provider to fail injection.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - by the time ex2.js is loaded by ajax, ex1.js has already been run, so needed and ex1 should already exist, (as recipes at least) within mainModule. Whenever I try to inject ex2 into that function shouldn't it also instantiate and inject needed if it didn't exist previous, or just inject if it had already been instantiated? Within that success handler, I confirmed that recipes exist for all 3 services. Does $injector.has or $injector.invoke throw if a recipe hasn't been instantiated yet? If so, can I manually instantiate the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS will bootstrap a module when it's loaded. During bootstrapping all the dependencies are initialized by the injector.

```
angular.module('mainModule').service('ex2', .....);
```

When you do the above via AJAX it happens *after* the `mainModule` has already been bootstrapped. The `service()` will queue the provider for bootstrapping, but bootstrapping never happens again.

This is from the manual on bootstrapping angular.

> You should call angular.bootstrap() after you've loaded or defined your modules. You cannot add controllers, services, directives, etc after an application bootstraps.

What I think you can do is create a new module, and attach it to the existing module.

So your AJAX code might look like this.

```
angular.module('ex2Module',[]).service('ex2', .....);
angular.module('mainModule').requires.push('ex2Module');
$rootScope.$digest();
```

I can not test this, but I think this will cause the new module `ex2Module` to be bootstrapped and added as a dependency to the existing `mainModule`. The injector should see this module as queued for bootstrapping and install it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: gotcha, I've been digging through the documentation looking for something that says exactly that. However, I did not know that you could attach modules like so, definately worth a shot. Powers out right now, so I'll try a little later when I can get to the code.

Comment: I was hopeful, but this yields the same result, with angular throwing an exception saying Unknown provider: ex2Provider <- ex2 . When I print out the _invokeQueue, it does not contain the recipe for ex2 with these changes.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis I found a project on Github for lazy loading modules and directives. Maybe this will offer some clues. https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy